# How to efficiently perform union of two queries with two different table with group by Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that performs a union between two select statements one that uses group by and another that doesn't. The problem is I'm selecting the same columns and using the same functions in both select statements. It feels I'm duplicating the code and I wish to know if there's a better way to write this

I've tried to use the normal union function to two select statements, but both select statements use the same functions. Is there a way to simplify the following query without duplication?

ex:

```
select state, count(*) 
from table1

union

select state, count(*)  
from table2
group by state
```

Comment: The first query in your union won't even run.  Have you tried running this code?  Sample data would be very helpful.

Comment: It looks like (sample data and desired results would be very helpful) you are trying to provide a *total* row. If so you are doing it the only way you can. However one normally does that in the presentation layer because as you say you've already got the data, you just want to display totals under you columns. So instead of giving SQL Server more work, just have your front end provide totals for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This query is wrongly written. you can try to run the "right" query on each table first, than use external "select" from outside with sum to get the final result you need: code sample:

```
select state, sum(total) from (
select state, count(id) as total from tablea group by state
union
select state, count(id) as total from tableb group by state) as t3
group by state
```